# closure of bounded set in uniform space

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

I have stumbled upon the following statement but I could not see why it is true. Let $(X,V)$ be a uniform space and $A$ bounded in it. *Bounded* means that  for each  $W\in V $ there is a finite set $F\subseteq X$ and an integer m, s.t. $A\subseteq W^m[F]$. So the statement says that in such a case, $\overline A\subseteq W^{m+1}[F]$. Can someone explain why that is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y\in\overline A$, then there is some $x\in A\cap W^{-1}(y)\subseteq W^m[F]\cap W^{-1}(y)$, thus $(x,y)\in W$, and there is an $f\in F$ and $f=x_0,x_1,\dots,x_m=x$ such that $(x_i,x_{i+1})\in W$ for all $i$. It then follows that $(f,y)\in W^{m+1}$.

Comment: you are assuming $W^{-1}$(y) is open. Why you know you can assume that?

Comment: @AvivEshed: We know that $W^{-1}(y)$ is a neighborhood of $y$. It may not be open, but that's not necessary here.

Comment: sorry again, I am just getting deeper into this material. How do I know that it must contain some open set which has y as its element?

Comment: @AvivEshed: The uniform structure $V$ induces the topology on $X$. Namely, the (not necessarily open) neighborhoods of some point $y$ taken to be of the form $W(y)=\{x\in X\mid (y,x)\in W\}$ for $W\in V$. Using the axioms of a uniform structure, it is easy to show that $(W(y))_{W\in V}$ is a neighborhood system for $y$. And all these neighborhood systems together then form the topology on $X$.